# php date validation

Tags: php, validation, date

Im trying to to set up a php date validation (MM/DD/YYYY) but I'm having issues. Here is a sample of what I got:

```
$date_regex = '%\A(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d\z%'; 

$test_date = '03/22/2010'; 
if (preg_match($date_regex, $test_date,$_POST['birthday']) ==true) {
    $errors[] = 'user name most have no spaces';`
```

Comment: consider how the date is supplied in the first instance.A client side date picker will greatly reduce the change of getting wrongly formatted dates.

Comment: Just try to create a DateTime object with the supplied string.  If that fails then the date was invalid

Comment: @user557846 You shouldn't depend on client side to ensure correct data.  It's so easily bypassed it should not be considered reliable.  It should only be considered an aid to the user, in that it helps them make fewer invalid form submissions.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You could use [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php). For example, something like this:

```
$test_date = '03/22/2010';
$test_arr  = explode('/', $test_date);
if (checkdate($test_arr[0], $test_arr[1], $test_arr[2])) {
    // valid date ...
}
```

A more paranoid approach, that doesn't blindly believe the input:

```
$test_date = '03/22/2010';
$test_arr  = explode('/', $test_date);
if (count($test_arr) == 3) {
    if (checkdate($test_arr[0], $test_arr[1], $test_arr[2])) {
        // valid date ...
    } else {
        // problem with dates ...
    }
} else {
    // problem with input ...
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution as it also checks for invalid dates, e.g. Feb 29. A pure regex approach based on formatting would allow invalid dates.

Comment: +1 for a regexless solution. Not all problems need a regex solution.

Comment: regex solution also checked for a format, while this doesn't. If string `foobar` is passed - you'll get notices

Comment: Let's come into the 21st century. [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) and [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](http://php.net/datetime.getlasterrors). Thank me later.

Comment: @salathe has the best approach. Nicolás should really update his answer as it's providing an old approach of doing this.

Comment: Everyone, in multiple posts, keeps saying to use checkdate.  But checkdate fails if the year is : 2, 20, 202, 2020 or even 20201 - it returns true every time.

Comment: @rolinger Why should checkdate fail with such years??? First: are they invalid years? Second: the documentation for `checkdate` explicitly states that: "The year is between 1 and 32767 inclusive."

Answer (score 56):

You can use some methods of the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime) class, which might be handy; namely, [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) in conjunction with [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](http://php.net/datetime.getlasterrors).

```
$test_date = '03/22/2010';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $test_date);
$date_errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
if ($date_errors['warning_count'] + $date_errors['error_count'] > 0) {
    $errors[] = 'Some useful error message goes here.';
}
```

This even allows us to see what actually caused the date parsing warnings/errors (look at the `warnings` and `errors` arrays in `$date_errors`).

Comment: It's worth to mention that you can check it straight with `DateTime::createFromFormat()` only, by checking if it's false, so `if(DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $test_date) === false) exit('bad date format');`

Comment: Only very crudely @s3m3n. For example, without checking for warnings, "44/33/2211" is a **valid** `m/d/Y` date (it is `2nd Sep 2214` btw).

Comment: You are right, but in my case I'm only validating if moderator didn't make literal mistake in date format which is going directly to database instead of logical sense of given date. Someone else might need the same thing.

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Comment: This is not **always** the best approach. If you receive the input already in separated values, but you don't know how exactly they are formatted (`M` vs. `MM`, `YYYY` vs. `YY`), I think `checkdate` would be more flexible and accept anything that resembles a valid date. Additionaly, with `DateTime`, if I write `31` as the **month** it will be considered valid, and simply add `2` years and set it to July (since `31%12 = 7`). I really don't think this would be expected behaviour by many people…

Comment: Important to note that @s3m3n's comment may no longer be correct. In PHP8, attempting this with a date like 3/31/2023 will NOT return `false` while the date is actually invalid.  Using `DateTime::getLastErrors();` from the answer does work as it should in this example.

Answer (score 32):

Though `checkdate` is good, this seems much concise function to validate and also you can give formats. [[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)]

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

The extra `->format()` is needed for cases where the date is invalid but `createFromFormat` still manages to create a DateTime object. For example:

```
// Gives "2016-11-10 ..." because Thursday falls on Nov 10
DateTime::createFromFormat('D M j Y', 'Thu Nov 9 2016');

// false, Nov 9 is a Wednesday
validateDate('Thu Nov 9 2016', 'D M j Y');
```

Comment: Why/when is the extra verification `$d->format($format) == $date` needed?

Comment: @Gras Double - Validation. He's returning true/false, but ensuring that the DateTime object was created and that the formatted DateTime equals the function input $date.

Comment: Sure, but a `return (bool) $d;` would do it. My question was, as the createFromFormat succeeded, in what scenario could the `$d->format()` be different from the input?

Comment: I have found this: `validateDate('Mon, 21-Jan-2041 15:24:52 GMT', DateTime::COOKIE);`. Returns false because the `->format()` produces "Monday" instead of "Mon". Though, it would be better to return true, as the input is valid. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Found out a purpose for the `->format()` verification. Answer updated again.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of the bulky [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object .. just use the core [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
function isValidDate($date, $format= 'Y-m-d'){
    return $date == date($format, strtotime($date));
}
```

Comment: Why not just test if strtotime() === false?

Comment: Testing if strtotime() === false checks the validity of the date, but not that it's in the desired format.

Answer (score 4):

Use it:

```
function validate_Date($mydate,$format = 'DD-MM-YYYY') {

    if ($format == 'YYYY-MM-DD') list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $mydate);
    if ($format == 'YYYY/MM/DD') list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', $mydate);
    if ($format == 'YYYY.MM.DD') list($year, $month, $day) = explode('.', $mydate);

    if ($format == 'DD-MM-YYYY') list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $mydate);
    if ($format == 'DD/MM/YYYY') list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $mydate);
    if ($format == 'DD.MM.YYYY') list($day, $month, $year) = explode('.', $mydate);

    if ($format == 'MM-DD-YYYY') list($month, $day, $year) = explode('-', $mydate);
    if ($format == 'MM/DD/YYYY') list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $mydate);
    if ($format == 'MM.DD.YYYY') list($month, $day, $year) = explode('.', $mydate);       

    if (is_numeric($year) && is_numeric($month) && is_numeric($day))
        return checkdate($month,$day,$year);
    return false;           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nicolas solution is best.  If you want in regex,

try this,

this will validate for, 01/01/1900 through 12/31/2099  Matches invalid dates such as February 31st Accepts dashes, spaces, forward slashes and dots as date separators

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: But why would you want regex in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

REGEX should be a last resort. PHP has a few functions that will validate for you. In your case, checkdate is the best option. http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 3):

This function working well,

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'm/d/Y'){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I've developed the following function for validating a date:

```
function IsDateTime($aDateTime) {
    try {
        $fTime = new DateTime($aDateTime);
        $fTime->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ksimka Actually yes, see [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation#22942735).

Comment: The call to format will throw an exception if the date is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
/^(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])((T|\s)(0[0-9]{1}|1[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})\:(0[0-9]{1}|1[0-9]{1}|2[0-9]{1}|3[0-9]{1}|4[0-9]{1}|5[0-9]{1})\:(0[0-9]{1}|1[0-9]{1}|2[0-9]{1}|3[0-9]{1}|4[0-9]{1}|5[0-9]{1})((\+|\.)[\d+]{4,8})?)?$/
```

this regular expression valid for :

- 2017-01-01T00:00:00+0000
- 2017-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
- 2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
- 2017-01-01 00:00:00+0000
- 2017-01-01

Remember that this will be cover all case of date and date time with (**-**) character

Comment: This question has already had plenty of far superior answers, what's more it's years old.  Your answer adds nothing.  Please don't indulge in necromancing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer the question or going to help....

```
$dt = '6/26/1970' ; // or // '6.26.1970' ;

$dt = preg_replace("([.]+)", "/", $dt);

$test_arr  = explode('/', $dt);

if (checkdate($test_arr[0], $test_arr[1], $test_arr[2]) && preg_match("/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/", $dt))

     { echo(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$dt")) . "<br>"); }

   else

     { echo "no good...format must be in mm/dd/yyyy"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple "date" input type, like below:

```
Birth date: <input type="date" name="userBirthDate" /><br />
```

Then we can link DateTime interface with built-in function 'explode':

```
public function validateDate()
    {
        $validateFlag = true;
        $convertBirthDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->birthDate);
        $birthDateErrors = DateTime::getLastErrors();

        if ($birthDateErrors['warning_count'] + $birthDateErrors['error_count'] > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['wrongDateFormat'] = "The date format is wrong.";
        }

        else
        {
            $testBirthDate = explode('-', $this->birthDate);
            if ($testBirthDate[0] < 1900)
            {
                $validateFlag = false;
                $_SESSION['wrongDateYear'] = "We suspect that you did not born before XX century.";
            }
        }

        return $validateFlag;
    }
```

I tested it on Google Chrome and IE, everything works correctly. Furthemore, Chrome display simple additional interface. If you don't write anything in input or write it in bad format (correctly is following: '1919-12-23'), you will get the first statement. If you write everything in good format, but you type wrong date (I assumed that nobody could born before XX century), your controller will send the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it will help somebody**.

```
function isValidDate($thedate) {
    $data = [
        'separators' => array("/", "-", "."),
        'date_array' => '',
        'day_index' => '',
        'year' => '',
        'month' => '',
        'day' => '',
        'status' => false
    ];

    // loop through to break down the date
    foreach ($data['separators'] as $separator) {
        $data['date_array'] = explode($separator, $thedate);
        if (count($data['date_array']) == 3) {
            $data['status'] = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // err, if more than 4 character or not int
    if ($data['status']) {
        foreach ($data['date_array'] as $value) {
            if (strlen($value) > 4 || !is_numeric($value)) {
                $data['status'] = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // get the year
    if ($data['status']) {
        if (strlen($data['date_array'][0]) == 4) {
            $data['year'] = $data['date_array'][0];
            $data['day_index'] = 2;
        }elseif (strlen($data['date_array'][2]) == 4) {
            $data['year'] = $data['date_array'][2];
            $data['day_index'] = 0;
        }else {
            $data['status'] = false;
        }
    }

    // get the month
    if ($data['status']) {
        if (strlen($data['date_array'][1]) == 2) {
            $data['month'] = $data['date_array'][1];
        }else {
            $data['status'] = false;
        }
    }

    // get the day
    if ($data['status']) {
        if (strlen($data['date_array'][$data['day_index']]) == 2) {
            $data['day'] = $data['date_array'][$data['day_index']];
        }else {
            $data['status'] = false;
        }
    }

    // finally validate date
    if ($data['status']) {
        return checkdate($data['month'] , $data['day'], $data['year']);
    }

    return false;
}
```