# preg_match help from an input box

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, preg-match

```
I need to validate a Date from an input box.
```

The regular expression is fine but that is about it. 
First where in the scope does it go, and second can you help make this work?
 When it validates I dont want it to echo anything and when it doesnt I would like it to
 tell the user that they must enter it in mm/dd/yyyy format. If you can do this in an alert box that would be even better! Thank you fellow developers!!! The COMPLETE code follows the  tag. Youll see my preg_match is commented out. Thank you fellow developers!!!

```
$input = '<input value="Date" type="text" name="date">';

if (preg_match('/^(|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0… $input)) {
echo "";
} else {
echo "You must Re-enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format.";
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<embed src="Songs/nature.mp3" width=10 height=10 autostart=true repeat=true loop=true></embed>
    <title>Post Song</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Post New Song</h1>
    <hr />
    <br />
    <body background="Songs/back.jpg">

    <form action= "Postsong.php" method="POST">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Song:</span>
        <input value="" type="text" name="song" />
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Artist Name:</span>
        <input value="" type="text" name="name" />
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Date:</span>
        <input value="" type="text" name="date" /><br />
        <br />
        <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit"
        value="Post Song" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <p>
    <a href="working.php">View Songs</a>
    </p>



    <?php

/*
    $input = '<input value="Date" type="text" name="date">';

    if (preg_match('/^(|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2\d)|(3[0-1]))\/((\d{4}))$/', $input)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "You must Re-enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format.";
}

*/

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $Song = stripslashes($_POST['song']);
        $Name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
        $Date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);
        $Song= str_replace("~", "-", $Song);
        $Name = str_replace("~", "-", $Name);
        $Date = str_replace("~", "-", $Date);
        $ExistingSubjects = array();
        if (file_exists(
            "Songs/songs.txt") &&
            filesize("Songs/songs.txt")
            > 0) {
            $SongArray = file(
                "Songs/songs.txt");
            $count = count($SongArray);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
                $CurrSong = explode("~",
                    $SongArray[$i]);
                $ExistingSubjects[] = $CurrSong[0];
            }
        }
        if (in_array($Song, $ExistingSubjects)) {
            echo "<p>The song you entered
                already exists!<br />\n";
            echo "Please enter a new song and
                try again.<br />\n";                        // Do I need another if statement saying if empty echo you need to enter something?...
            echo "Your song was not saved.</p.";
            $Song = "";
        }
        else {
        $SongRecord =
            "$Song~$Name~$Date~\n";
        $SongFile = fopen(
            "Songs/songs.txt",
            "ab");
        if ($SongFile === FALSE)
            echo "There was an error saving your
                song!\n";
        else {
            fwrite($SongFile, 
                $SongRecord);
            fclose($SongFile);
            echo "Your song has been 
            saved.\n";
            $Song = "";
            $Name = "";
            $Date = "";
        }
    }
}
    else {
        $Song = "";
        $Name = "";
        $Date = "";
    }




    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: First of all learn basics of PHP and/or JavaScript which you are clearly lacking. Format your code. Also you haven't searched much for the answer since validation is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation

Comment: Don't use regexes to validate numeric values.  This is a solved problem. People have already written, tested and debugged code that handles this already. Whenever you have a programming problem that others have probably had to deal with in the past, then look for existing code that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches for mm/dd/yyyy

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))/\d{4}
```

The first part i.e. `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` checks for two digits ranging from `01` to `12`.

Next part i.e. `(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))` checks for two digits ranging from `01` to `31`.

Next part i.e. `\d{4}`  checks for 4 digits.

`/` between the parts checks for `/` as separator.