# How can I validate UTC date

Tags: php

I'd like to validate UTC date, sent by the POST request, before inserting it into my database.

```
$date = "2014-08-11T16:32:13.000Z"
```

What is the best way to check if the date is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: The following answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22942735/283078

Comment: @MarkM I mean it doesn't contains illegal characters, non-existent days etc. Example `2014-88-55T16:32:13.000Z` or `2014---08-11T16:32:13.000Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
  $dt = new DateTime($date);
  // $dt->format(DateTime::ATOM); // contains valid date
}catch(Exception $exception) {
  // invalid $date
}
```