# How to ignore Unidentified index? php mysql

Tags: php

I have unidentified index errors, and sometimes i need it to really be blank.

for example this one. I need this one to be blank because there is already an else statement.

the $_GET is only when the user inputs a date.

```
$datefrom   = $_GET['datefrom'];
$dateto     = $_GET['dateto'];
if(isset($_GET['datefrom']) && ($_GET['dateto'])){
    $qry = "SELECT sum(order_detail.quantity*order_detail.price) as chenes, orders.date 
        FROM order_detail 
        LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON order_detail.orderid=orders.serial
        WHERE date(orders.date) BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'";
}
else {
    $qry = "SELECT sum(order_detail.quantity*order_detail.price) as chenes, orders.date 
        FROM order_detail 
        LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON order_detail.orderid=orders.serial";
}
```

how do i ignore the unidentified index error or remove it even if there is a blank? Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of a thing called “SQL injection”?

Comment: Don't ignore it. Fix it.

Comment: @sevenseacat I know why it is displaying the error, the $datefrom and $dateto is blank, how do i catch that error? If it's blank it wont display the error.

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP manual?

Comment: The error message contains a line number. Locate that line and fix. Yes, `isset` is the right way (one of them actually) but you need to use it at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you try to access the two indexes 'datefrom' and 'dateto' before actually checking whether they exist using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Put the first two assignments after your if-statement like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['datefrom']) && isset($_GET['dateto'])){
    $datefrom   = $_GET['datefrom'];
    $dateto     = $_GET['dateto'];
    // ...
```

Also note that you are vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!

Comment: It is better to use `empty()` than `isset()`. `empty()` does the same as `isset()` but also checks if it is empty or not

Comment: `$_GET['datefrom']` might also contain an empty string. Think of an  input field where the user manually has to specify the date in YYYY-MM-DD, for example. In that case, `empty()` would also return true.

Answer (score 0):

Although andy's answer will fix your immediate problem, you have a *lot* of work to do to make this even *somewhat* bullet resistant.

You must check that, if one date is supplied, so is the other one.  You must check that they're valid dates in a valid format: [php date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation)

Finally, to further guard against SQL injection attacks, you need to use "bind parameters," which make the DBMS use those parameters as data, no matter if they look like SQL: [How to bind SQL variables in Php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860130/how-to-bind-sql-variables-in-php)

Checking that the dates are valid is *not* a sufficient guard against SQL injection because you are betting there's not some other error somewhere.