# PHP: DateTime::__construct() error

Tags: php

I keep getting the following error :

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (46-61-9481) at position 0 (4): Unexpected character

which relates to this piece of script within an API

```
 $dob = new DateTime(str_replace('/','-',Input::post('date_of_birth')));
  $customer->date_of_birth = $dob->getTimestamp();
```

I have quite limited knowledge when it comes to code but, I'm wondering if anyone would be kind enough to let me know what to change to avoid these errors.

Comment: Surely it doesn't require much coding knowledge to recognise that `46-61-9481` is unlikely to be recognised as a valid date in most calendar systems

Comment: The errors happen when a customer puts the wrong date in to the form. Regardless of what they put in, i still want the form to submit the details - we can amend the date when we speak to the customer.

Comment: Perhaps use [date_parse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) first, and only create the DateTime object if it doesn't give you a Boolean false return

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the use of DateTime(). PHP DateTime() expects a valid date and otherwise it will throw an exception. If you still want to accept invalid date input, better to put this in a try catch block. If the date is a valid one, it will work well and otherwise it will come to catch block. In the catch block, you can set a default date such as 00/00/0000 and save to DB.

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime('01-01-2016');
    $date = $date->format('m/d/Y');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $date = '00/00/0000';
}

echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

`46` is not a valid month, nor a valid day of month. A valid month or day of month never starts with a `4`.

The date `46-61-9481` is invalid, hence the error.

The solution is to [validate the input date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation) prior to passing it to `DateTime` constructor.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the fact they put in a wrong date isn't an issue, we can amend the date when we speak to the customer, i still want the form to submit regardless of whether the date is correct or not. Is there anything i can do to ensure the form is submitted regardless of what date the customer puts.

Comment: Well, you can, for example, check that the date-string is valid and if it is not, you can: Show an error message _or_ set `$customer->date_of_birth` to `null`.