# How to validate date range in format d.m.Y - d.m.Y in PHP

Tags: php, regex, date-range

My string always looks like this:

```
04.01.2018 - 20.01.2018
```

So the pattern is: `d.m.Y - d.m.Y`

I thought REGEX would be the first choice. Comments says not to use REGEX.

Any suggestions on how to validate it?

Comment: Do you want to validate if they are digits only?

Comment: By not using a regex. Regexes are really awkward for numeric ranges, even more so for dates, which require complex dependent validation (max number of days in a month, etc).

Comment: @Thefourthbird if the given string matches this pattern

Comment: You haven't specified what exactly "this pattern" is.

Comment: @melpomene any suggestions about validating if pattern matches?

Comment: @melpomene d.m.Y - d.m.Y

Comment: Yes; what does that mean?

Comment: @melpomene `day.month.year - day.month.year`

Comment: ... What exactly does that mean? Can you actually explain what you want instead of just repeating yourself?

Comment: @Terminus Your selected answer DOES NOT validate a date range.  The dates may not be valid dates at all.  They may be in reverse order; does this matter?  If you require real validation, do not use regex (as mel said early on). Please explain how strict your validation needs to be for your task/project -- I can only assume it needs to be stronger than what the accepted answer offers.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is definitely not the way.  Split the string, and use a date-based method to validate each date.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be92bde2da9d784cfb80e10e7ebe61f437489b80))

```
function valiDate($date,$format='d.m.Y'){
    $d=DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$date);
    return $d && $d->format($format)==$date;
}

function regex($date){
    return preg_match('/^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} - \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$/',$date);
}
/* or 
    function valiDate($date){
        $date=DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y',$date);
        $date_errors=DateTime::getLastErrors();
        if($date_errors['warning_count'] || $date_errors['error_count']){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
*/
// both valiDate functions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation

$dateranges=[
    '04.01.2018 - 20.01.2018',
    '01.01.2017 - 01.02.201s',
    '00.00.0000 - 99.99.9999',
    "fish\t\t\t\t\t",
    '31.02.2018 - 31.03.2019',
    '12.13.2016 - 12.14.2016',
    '04.04.2018 - 04.04.2017'
];
foreach($dateranges as $daterange){  
    $dates=explode(' - ',$daterange,2);
    echo "($daterange}) ";
    echo 'valiDate: ',(isset($dates[1]) && valiDate($dates[0]) && valiDate($dates[1]))?'valid':'bonk';
    echo "\t-VS-\t";
    echo 'regex: ',regex($daterange)?'valid':'bonk';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
(04.01.2018 - 20.01.2018}) valiDate: valid  -VS-    regex: valid
(01.01.2017 - 01.02.201s}) valiDate: bonk   -VS-    regex: bonk
(00.00.0000 - 99.99.9999}) valiDate: bonk   -VS-    regex: valid
(fish                   }) valiDate: bonk   -VS-    regex: bonk
(31.02.2018 - 31.03.2019}) valiDate: bonk   -VS-    regex: valid
(12.13.2016 - 12.14.2016}) valiDate: bonk   -VS-    regex: valid
(04.04.2018 - 04.04.2017}) valiDate: valid  -VS-    regex: valid
```

p.s. I added the `isset()` call to avoid Notices when two elements are not generated from `explode()`.

Comment: Definitely the way to go, you can even add a simple comparison of DateTime instance to check if the range is valid.