# How do I validate February days count in specific year?

Tags: php, date

How to validate specific date ? For example user types 29-12-2005. Of course I can validate it with regular expression etc.. But 2005 year had not 29 days in February. Any date functions and methods did not help me.

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Last day of this month`

For example

```
echo (new DateTime('1-12-2005'))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('d');
```

Output:

```
31
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8677eefcefb14c7dbc2c1b4faffdac6b8515d0d)

Note this is for Dec (12).   If you do it for `1-2-2005` it's 28, you don't want to necessarily use 29, because DateTime will kick it into the next month, which brings us to this one.

Simply check the date (it should be the same if its a valid day):

```
$date = '29-2-2005';

echo (new DateTime($date))->format('d-m-Y') == $date  ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Output:

```
false //ex. 1-3-2005 == 29-2-2005 is false
```

And then of course there is this way:

```
$date = explode('-','29-2-2005');

var_dump(checkdate( $date[1], $date[0], $date[2] ));
```

Also `false`, but the disadvantage of checkdate is you need to know the format of the date ahead of time.  Using DateTime, it will accept multiple formats without issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple function in PHP to check number of days in a month for a given year:

```
cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2005); // 28
```